# Sharepoint User Login

Tags: 2010, active-directory, login

Recently I have a problem that new Active Directory users cannot log into Sharepoint.

All other functionality seems fine, but it appears to be failing to create new user accounts.

To me, it looks like the FIM service was never setup and working so it appeared to be validating users in a different way, but I am not sure how this used to be working.

The only change which has occured between new users being able to log in was a rebuild of the primary domain controller after it had a corrupted disk. This means that the primary domain controller has been changed to a new server, although I cannot see why this might cause an issue.

Comment: Are the new users added to SP either directly or via AD groups? Did you recreate the AD instance on the PDC or was there a BDC in place?

Comment: I have 3 domain controllers, so I just did an emergency transfer of domain ownership onto one of the other DC's. New users are added to SP using an security group.

Comment: FIM is mainly used for the User Profile Service, for sync'ing user profiles. Not required for log in. SharePoint connects directly with AD to validate the user. Can SharePoint server ping the domain name? ping the new PDC?

Comment: Yes it can, where is sharepoint setup to read AD?

Comment: It's an auto-magical feature. It assumes the AD domain it's installed on. You can configure it to point to specific ADs or completely separate auth stores by using the web.config file. It may be a good idea and check out the web.config, ensure your domain is not configured specifically in there.

Comment: The problem is, its installed on one of my DC's, so normally I would try just taking it off the domain and putting it back on, but not too sure about that. Nothing in either web.configs

Comment: You have SP installed on a DC?

Comment: Yes, installed before my time.

Comment: Installing SP on a DC is not a supported scenario, however it's done all the time on development environments. Can you reboot the server? Can you confirm the SP DC is receiving AD updates? Check AD logs, Event Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out the problem was with the auto-magical feature of reading domain information from the server.

When the previous PDC failed and the domain was transferred to another DC, it looks like the synchronization between the other DC's and the DC that sharepoint was installed on failed.

Force removing the DC from the domain, cleaning up the metadata, and rejoining it to the domain solved the issue.